# vba access function for extract cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a function for extract cell string value of the first previous valorized cell of a certain column.

I try to explain better:
I've a column in witch not all cells cointans values.
So if I want to build a function that accept as parameter 1 cell, e.g. 'A5'.
If into A5 cell there is not any value it check if previous cell (A4) has some value. If fails again it recursively go back (A3..A2..A1) until it find something.

```
Public Function getPreviousValorizedCellValue(ByVal cell As Range) As String
If (cell.Value = "") Then
    Set cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0)
    getPreviousValorizedCellValue (cell)
Else: getPreviousValorizedCellValue = cell.Value
End If
End Function
```

It doesnt work. Excel give me error

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Public Sub TestgetPrevious()
    Dim cell As Range

    Set cell = ActiveSheet.Range("A5")

    MsgBox getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2(cell)
End Sub


Public Function getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2(ByVal cell As Range) As String
    Debug.Print cell.Address

    If cell.Row <= 0 Then Exit Function

    If (Trim(cell.Value = "")) Then
        If cell.Row > 1 Then
            Set cell = cell.Offset(-1, 0)

            getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2 = getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2(cell)
        Else
            getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2 = ""
        End If
    Else
        getPreviousValorizedCellValue_v2 = cell.Value
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Glad I could help.  You almost got it. The main thing missing was :" getPreviousValorizedCellValue = getPreviousValorizedCellValue(cell) "

Comment: damn! obvious missing! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below Code.

```
Function Foo(iRange As Range)

For i = iRange.Row To 1 Step -1
    If Trim(Range("A" & i).Value) <> "" Then
        Foo = Range("A" & i).Value 'Put the code you want here
        Exit Function
    End If
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I want a function that return me the string representing value of first valorized previous cell. Not a procedure. And the cell should be passed as ByVal cell.

Comment: @mastro: Then put this perfectly adequate code in a function yourself!

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. :) have edited the code anyways for mastro's benefit

Comment: @mastro have modified the procedure to a function now :)

Comment: Public Function getPreviousValorizedCellValue2(ByVal cell As Range) As String
    For i = cell.row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, cell.column).Value <> "" Then
        getPreviousValorizedCellValue2 = cell.Value
        End If
    Next i
        
End Function

Excel now tell me that the function cannot be applied because I pass a empy cell.

Comment: Are you using the function within a workbook cell? or within another procedue?

Comment: @izzymo , thanks for the help, I thing that recursive version of function is more elegant and efficient! Anyway thanks! :)